Yolop output giving NaN values on SNPE android
i have used YOLOP model and converted into dlc file using SNPE SDK. created input tensor and build the network. Taking output tensor values give list of NaN values. given below show how i configure network, pass input tensors. but my variables laneLineSeg, and DetOutValues are NaN values. Any one can help me on this?
This is how i configure network, pass input tensors. but my variables laneLineSeg,DrivAreaSegValues and DetOutValues are NaN values.
private val modelName = "yolop_seg.dlc"
private fun configureNetwork(): NeuralNetwork? {
        return try {

            val assetInputStream = applicationContext.assets.open(modelName)
            val network = SNPE.NeuralNetworkBuilder(application)
                .setDebugEnabled(false)
                .setRuntimeOrder(NeuralNetwork.Runtime.GPU_FLOAT16)
                .setModel(assetInputStream, assetInputStream.available())
                .setCpuFallbackEnabled(true)
                .setUseUserSuppliedBuffers(false)
                .setUnsignedPD(false)
                .setCpuFixedPointMode(false)
                .setOutputLayers("Sigmoid_1671","Concat_1534", "Sigmoid_1808" )

                .build()
            assetInputStream.close()
            network
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("NETWORK", e.message.toString())
            null
        }
    }
 private fun getClassificationResult(network: NeuralNetwork, bitmap: Bitmap): FloatArray{
        val image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 640, 640, true)
        
        val inputsMap: MutableMap<String, FloatTensor> = HashMap()
        val inputNames: Set<String> = network.inputTensorsNames
        val outputNames: Set<String> = network.outputTensorsNames
        var mInputLayer = ""
        val mOutputLayer = ""
        mInputLayer = inputNames.iterator().next()

        val tensor = network.createFloatTensor(1, 640, 640,3)
        val dimension = tensor.shape
        val isGrayScale = (dimension[dimension.size - 1] == 1)

        val input: FloatArray = if (!isGrayScale) {
            loadRgbBitmapAsFloat(image)
        } else {
            loadGrayScaleBitmapAsFloat(image)
        }
        tensor.write(input, 0, input.size)
        inputsMap[mInputLayer] = tensor
        val outputsMap = network.execute(inputsMap)

        val driveAreaSeg = outputsMap["drive_area_seg"]
        val DrivAreaSegValues = FloatArray(driveAreaSeg!!.size)
        driveAreaSeg.read(DrivAreaSegValues, 0, DrivAreaSegValues.size)
        val i = 0

        val laneLineSeg = outputsMap["lane_line_seg"]
        val LanLinSegValues = FloatArray(laneLineSeg!!.size)
        laneLineSeg.read(LanLinSegValues, 0, LanLinSegValues.size)

        val detOut = outputsMap.get("det_out")
        val DetOutValues = FloatArray(detOut!!.size)
        detOut.read(DetOutValues, 0, DetOutValues.size)

        return laneLineSeg


